# Почему не обновляется нужный item notifyItemChanged() а последний видимый в списке?

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

У меня у каждого item-a списка есть кнопка, при нажатии на нее она скрывается и появляется на ее месте progress бар и одновременно с нажатием на кнопку посылается запрос. Как при удачном ответе с сервера спрятать бар и поменять фон у кнопки? Я почитал что это будет делать функция `notifyItemChanged()` и вот мой адаптер:

```
open class JobsAdapter(private val jobs: ArrayList<JobModel>, private val ctx: Context, private val click: Click) : RecyclerView.Adapter<JobsAdapter.JobsHolder>() {
    lateinit var view: View


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, p1: Int): JobsHolder {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.job_list_item, viewGroup, false)
        return JobsHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return jobs.size
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: JobsHolder, position: Int) {
        val jobModel = jobs[position]
        holder.tvPosition.text = jobModel.position
        holder.tvAddress.text = jobModel.location
        holder.tvCompany.text = jobModel.company_name

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if (!jobModel.isSeen) {
                    Singleton.clickReq(jobModel.id, ctx)

            }

            holder.itemView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.message_list_item_bg)

            click.sendData(Uri.parse(jobModel.job_link).toString(), holder.adapterPosition, jobModel.position!!)
        }

        holder.ivAddTo.setOnClickListener {
            holder.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.ivAddTo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.added_to_notepad)
            holder.ivAddTo.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.ivAddTo.isClickable = false
            Singleton.jobLstPos = position



                saveToNotepad(jobModel.id)
        }


        if (jobModel.isSeen) {
            holder.itemView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.message_list_item_bg)
        } else {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fafafa"))
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: JobsHolder, position: Int, payloads: List<Any>) {
        if (payloads.isNotEmpty()) {
            when (payloads[0]) {
                1 -> {
                    holder.ivAddTo.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
        }
    }

    private fun saveToNotepad(id: Int) {
        Singleton.apiService(ctx).saveTo("Bearer " + ctx.getSharedPreferences("appD", 0).getString("access_token", ""), id).enqueue(object : Callback<SaveTo> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<SaveTo>, response: Response<SaveTo>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    notifyItemChanged(view.getTag(R.id.tag_3) as Int, 1)
                } 
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<SaveTo>, t: Throwable) {
            }
        })
    }

    class JobsHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var tvCompany = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_company)!!
        var tvDate = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_date)!!
        var tvPosition = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_job_title)!!
        var tvAddress = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_address)!!
        var ivAddTo = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.add_to_notepad)!!
        var progressBar = itemView.findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBar)
    }
}
```

но у меня обновляется последняя видимая запись в списке хотя я кликаю например на первую. В чем может быть проблема и как сделать то что я пытаюсь сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Вызывая `notifyItemChanged()` вы спровоцируете вызов `onBindViewHolder` для все отображенных элементов. В этом методе я вижу место, где вы показываете прогрессбар по клику кнопки, но в нем нет места, говорящего, что прогрессбар надо скрыть. Вы должны из данных  в `jobModel` понимать, надо ли показывать вам прогрессбар или нет, и либо скрывать его, либо показывать прям в самом onBindViewHolder, помимо того что вы делаете в слушателе кнопки.

Сейчас у вас возможна такая ситуация: вы кликаете по первому элементу списка. Пока прогрессбар крутится, вы тяните список вниз. Первая вюшка, в которой крутится прогрессбар, пропадает из зоты видимости, открепляется от списка и прикрепляется в конце для отображения другого джоба. И у этого джоба будет крутится прогрессбар, т.к. в `onBindViewHolder` вы его не скрыли

Итого, для того чтоб все работало как надо вам нужно следующее:

1. Из `position` в `onBindViewHolder` вы должны понимать, есть ли данные, нет их или идет запрос. Как это делать вариантов много. Можно прям в объекте состояние сохранять, можно вспомогательные создавать, можно еще чего придумать
2. В `onBindViewHolder` вы должны полностью обеспечивать подгонку вьюшки к состоянию джоба. Вы не можете исходить из некоторых исходных состояний, т.к. эта же вьюшка могла до этого отображать другой джоб